# Difference between "Find Usages" and "Find All References"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts

What's the difference between "Find Usages" and "Find All References" in Visual Studio (in particular, VS 2017)?  They generate a different UI window so they seem like distinct features.  When would they return a different set of results?

Comment: Do you have Resharper installed? Does one of those options disappear if you disable Resharper?

Comment: @mjwills Ah, that might explain why I can't find "Find Usages" it in my Visual Studio.

Comment: I do have ReSharper installed - great catch!  I'm thinking now that Find Usages is a ReSharper feature and perhaps does the same thing as Find All References.

Comment: @mjwills - feel free to post that as the answer so I can accept (that they are functionally the same, just that one is a VS feature and the other a ReSharper feature).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Find Usages` is a Resharper feature (i.e. not built into Visual Studio directly).

Comment: I find Resharper's Find Usages feature more powerful than Visual Studio's Find All References. Find All References sometimes doesn't find references in View files / aspx files while Resharper's Find Usages finds them